# Fetch in Safari 11.1 - request with console log doesn't work (ReadableStream uploading is not supported)

Tags: javascript, safari, fetch

After the last update of Safari browser (to 11.1) I noticed that my fetch code stopped working.

Code:

```
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  credentials: 'include',
  body: '{"id":"xxx","note":"yyy"}',
  headers: {}
};


options.headers = new window.Headers();
options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

function getRequest() {
  return new window.Request('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', options);
}

const newRe = getRequest();

console.log(newRe);

fetch(newRe)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((jsonObject) => {
  console.log(jsonObject)
    document.write(`ID ${jsonObject.id} was created!`);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    document.write(error);
  });
```

here on Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BrXoqG

on Safari 11.1 returns error: 'NotSupportedError: ReadableStream uploading is not supported'.
But, if you remove line with `console.log(newRe)`, everything works properly.

Why?

Comment: If a `console.log` changes code behaviour, I think what you have there is a *serious* bug to report - edit: already reported by the look of it [https://github.com/ServiceStack/Issues/issues/610](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Issues/issues/610) - solution is not to use `Request API` ... so `fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', options)` should work it seems

Comment: If instead of `document.writing` Error objects, you were actually `console.error`ing it, you would probably have seen that the bug is a codepen one, specifically in their *console_runner[...].js*, and probably because they try to access a property they're not allowed to access.

Comment: Bug is repeatable in pure code, not only in codepen. You can check it yourself.

Comment: Well you may have something else that does try to access Request.body, but I can't reproduce on e.g [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/996cyw5g/)

Comment: I opened this fiddle on Safari on Mac and there's same error...

Comment: Do you have a plugin that could overwrite default console.log? Definitely works for me. What's outputed in the console with this one https://jsfiddle.net/996cyw5g/2/ ? (Particularly the stack trace of the Error)

Comment: NotSupportedError: ReadableStream uploading is not supported
> fetch
> onload — _display:86

Comment: And are you sure you have the newest Safari? On previous versions it was working properly.

Comment: I do (11.1), and I can reproduce on codepen, not anywhere else where there is no console overwriting code.

Comment: For future reference, I've filed https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203617

Answer (score 3):

Safari doesn't seems to support fetch with a `Request` object having a `POST` method ; probably because now when you construct a `Request` object, the body is wrapped in a `ReadableStream`.

You may convert your `Request` object to a tuple of arguments:

```
const body = await request.clone().text();
const {cache, credentials, headers, integrity, mode, redirect, referrer} = request;
const init = {body, cache, credentials, headers, integrity, mode, redirect, referrer};
fetch(request.url, init);
```